# In Mongodb how does the cache get warmed up?

Tags: mongodb

I'm wondering how the cache (memory) gets warmed up.  I understand that MongoDB uses memory mapped files and the OS's virtual memory to swap pages in and out as needed.  What I don't understand is how it gets warmed up on startup.

Upon startup does mongod map all of the pages in the database to virtual memory or is there some other mechanism to load pages that are not yet mapped which get mapped as queries are run against the database?

Similarly, is the size of the database limited to the amount of virtual memory available to the system.  I understand that on a 64-bit system this is a lot.  Is there another mechanism other than memory mapping for pages to moved to and from disk?

Answer (score 1):

Memory mapping means that there is a representation of all the on disk files available but only a portion of these files may be present in RAM. When a given page is needed (and it is not in RAM) it can be read from disk into RAM to be accessed.

Regarding limitations, you can see them on the [MongoDB limits page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/)

MongoDB does not do any specific "warming" of pages on startup, as it does not have any concept of which pages would be useful and which not.

If you wish to "Warm" certain collections manually before using them you should look at the [touch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/touch/) command.